# editing cells in nstable view using cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

hi i have a NSTableView in a view controller class
i have added an button named as "Add"

When i click on the button then a new row gets added to the table which is blank using this code:

```
[myArray addObject:@""];
[myTable reloadData];
[myTable editColumn:0 row:[myArray count]-1 withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

now when i enter the data after that i press enter key but dont understand as which method is called so that i can update the myArray with the new content

cannot find which method gets invoked

any idea!!
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setObjectValue:` method of `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol gets called after you finish editing you cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;
```

Override this method to get the value you entered while you edited the cell. The value is passed though the `object` parameter. You can add that to your array.